# Best circuit to drive +5 V from 3.3 V IC

Tags: switching

I am using an ESP32 and I want to cut power to a 5 V component which should draw around 80 mA.

On my board I have 5 V, so I created two designs:

The first one uses an NPN transistor + P-mosfet -> [simulation on Falstad](http://tinyurl.com/275dh5fz)

The second one uses an N-MOSFET + P-MOSFET -> [simulation on Falstad](http://tinyurl.com/258jal98)

Both, to the best of my knowledge, seem to do the job.

The transistor solution seems to rely heavily on the value of the two resistors on the left. How do I properly size those?

Comment: Please use the schematic editor here. It's part of your question editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both versions look OK.

BTW, base of the NPN needs a pull-down also.

I wouldn’t use such a high Ib/Ic ratio. It should be about 1/10 (not 2.7 mA/500 μA as in your schematic).

Comment: I guess then 1k 200? but that would mean thatn there will be a 25mA wasted to gnd when the led is on no?

http://tinyurl.com/27hevhce

Comment: How about Rb=22k, Rc=4k7, R_pull_down=100k.

Answer (score 0):

I'm lazy. For this kind of thing, I just grab a chip from my drawer of TC1411s. Lots of other "gate driver" ICs that you could use...